# TV Guide PHP script / Database structure

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures

I was looking for PHP TV guide scripts with it's Database structure.
Or at least the Database Structure by itself.

Any help or infomration would be really appreciated, I just don't want to start from scratch.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to start from scratch? I think it can be pretty straight-forward;

```
- A master tables with Channels (id, name, description)
- A master table with programs (id, name, description)
- A table with the guide (id, datetime, program_id, channel_id)
```

Of course you can extend this simple start with program-categories (i.e. movie or quiz), attendees/actors.

Comment: Thanks, I have sketched that simple too but still wondering if there are other ideas that could have have been implemented to gather more experience.